# ldd says "not found" even though library is in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux

```
$ ldd libpmsfdcwrt.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x004ae000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00417000)
        [ ... elided ... ]
        libz.so.1 => not found
        [ ... elided ... ]
        libpmssl.so.0.9.7 (0xf5be8000)
        libfreebl3.so => /usr/lib/libfreebl3.so (0xf5b88000)
```

Note "libz.so.1 => not found".

But libz.so.1 exists:

```
$ ls -l /lib64/libz.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Apr 25  2013 /lib64/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3
$ ls -l /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 91096 Oct  3  2012 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
```

And, that directory is listed in LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
:/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib:/opt/CA/CAlib:/usr/local/CAlib:/opt/CA/WorkloadAutomationAE/autosys/lib:/opt/auto/ixpagent/lib:/lib64:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/lib:/usr/lib:/opt/CA/SharedComponents/Csam/SockAdapter/lib
```

(I logged out and logged back in to be sure it was sticking.)

Comment: What does `file /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3` output?

Comment: just to make sure - does `libz.so.1.2.3` exist?

Comment: What does `readelf -a libpmsfdcwrt.so | grep PATH` output? The library might have an rpath defined, overriding LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: $ file /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3 yields: /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Comment: The "readelf" command yields no output.

Comment: Huh.  The original shared object is "libpmsfdcwrt.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped", that's my problem?

Comment: No doubt :) Do you have a `/lib/libz.so.1`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem was a 32-bit/64-bit collision:

```
$ file libpmsfdcwrt.so
libpmsfdcwrt.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

$ file /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Thank you, everyone, for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

In our case LD_LIBRARY_PATH was correct, ldconfig could find it and the /etc/ld.so.conf.d files were all in place, yet when running debug on the linker it would skip right over the library:

```
LD_DEBUG=libs ldd <application>[ENTER]
```

(it would skip over the library while "searchinbg" and not find it).

Originally the binary was launched by a vendor script and the vendor script merely said the library could not be found.  After much digging we ran the binary by hand and got this error:

```
./<application> error while loading shared libraries: libclntsh.so.12.1: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

Immediately we know the application is 32-bit and the binary is 64-bit and so we need to get 32-bit versions of the library.

If we had run the binary by hand we would have found the problem a lot sooner.  NONE of the linker debug output that we had showed this.