# What could cause a conditional `ldd: library.so => not found` when that file exists and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is OK?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, googletest, ldd

### tl;dr

Under what circumstances could I expect to see `library.so => not found` when:

1. The linker search path is correct, as verified by other libraries in the same directory being linked.
2. The so file in question actually exists, is a regular file, is nonempty, and is linked successfully by other tests in the project.

### Background

I'm building a library project, call it `libspecific` which depends on a library, call it `libgeneric`. `libspecific` has a few submodules, two of which are relevant, call them `libspecific_base` and `libspecific_extension`. Both `libspecific_base` and `libspecific_extension` depend on a few libraries from `libgeneric`, call them `libgeneric_utils`, `libgeneric_math`, `libgeneric_geometry`, and `libgeneric_algorithms`. `libspecific_extension` also depends on `libspecific_base`.

Typically I want to install `libgeneric` from my company's internal apt repositories, but it's possible to build and install from source. In either case, the directory structure in /usr/lib/libgeneric looks like this:

```
/usr/lib/libgeneric
├── libgeneric_utils.so
├── libgeneric_math.so
├── libgeneric_geometry.so
└── libgeneric_algorithms.so
```

Installing from the internal apt repositories, I see something like

```
$ file libgeneric_geometry.so                                                                
libgeneric_geometry.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=6eba11784651535bdebd995af672589f99f95688, stripped
```

This makes sense, because debug symbols are built and then stripped and shipped in a separate -dev package.
If I build and install from source, but without debug symbols, I see pretty much what's above, only `not stripped` at the end.

### Problem

I'm trying to build tests for `libspecific_base`.
If I build and install from the `libgeneric` source, I have no problem.
If I use the pre-built libraries, I get this error:

```
/home/alan/projects/libspecific/cmake-build-release-coverage/libspecific_base_tests: error while loading shared libraries: libgeneric_geometry.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:77 (message):
  Error running test executable.

    Path: '/home/alan/projects/libspecific/cmake-build-release-coverage/libspecific_base_tests'
    Result: 127
    Output:
```

If I inspect `libspecific_base.so`, I get the following:

```
$ ldd libspecific_base.so | egrep -e '(libgeneric|geometry)'
    libgeneric_utils.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_utils.so (0x00007f7a798b9000)
    libgeneric_math.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_math.so (0x00007f7a77cc7000)
    libgeneric_algorithms.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_algorithms.so (0x00007f7a77a1c000)
    libgeneric_geometry.so => not found
```

So it can't be the case that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is wrong.
If I do `readelf -d libspecific_base.so | grep libgeneric`, I get:

```
$ readelf -d libspecific_base.so | grep libgeneric

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgeneric_utils.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgeneric_math.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgeneric_algorithms.so]
```

but no `libgeneric_geometry.so`. I also see /usr/lib/libgeneric when I do `readelf -d libspecific_base.so | grep RUNPATH`.

What's weird is that I can still build and run tests for `libspecific_extension`. If I inspect `libspecific_extension.so` I get:

```
$ ldd libspecific_extension.so | egrep -e '(libgeneric|geometry)'
    libgeneric_utils.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_utils.so (0x00007f7a798b9000)
    libgeneric_math.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_math.so (0x00007f7a77cc7000)
    libgeneric_geometry.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_geometry.so (0x00007fbfc6a85000)
    libgeneric_algorithms.so => /usr/lib/libgeneric/libgeneric_algorithms.so (0x00007f7a77a1c000)
```

### Question

I don't necessarily need a specific answer to this problem, but I would like to know what could cause this so I can investigate further. I'm far from an expert on linker.

Comment: So, unless I missed the main point of the problem, the only issue here is that the pre-built binaries don't contain that libgeneric_geometry.so?

Comment: They do contain it, it's just that `libspecific_base` fails to link against it while `libspecific_extension` doesn't fail.

Comment: Could it be that you only have one version of `libgeneric_geometry` in your system, let's say the non stripped version, and that `libspecific_extension.so` uses the non stripped version (great, found!) whereas `libspecific_base` links to the stripped version (ouch, not found!)? Something similar to what happened to this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25314983/260313

Comment: No, it turns out that `libspecific_extension.so` links to the stripped or the non-stripped versions without complaining one way or the other.

Comment: Reasons it wouldn't be found: *Incorrect LD_LIBRARY_PATH, rpath, etc. *The path/file doesn't exist *the file found is incompatible (like 32bit vs 64bit libraries).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug this kind of problem is by running the binary with `LD_DEBUG=files,libs`.

> So it can't be the case that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is wrong.

Yes, it can. In fact `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` may not be set *at all* -- you have `RUNPATH` set, and that is searched *before* `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. See `man ld.so`.

Also note that the best practice is to build binaries such that they don't need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Using the environment variable opens you to "works for me, but not for the other guy" bugs and unpredictability.

> I'm far from an expert on linker.

The linker is out of the picture by the time you are running an executable.

It's the runtime loader which performs searches for the libraries, and your question is mostly about the `ld.so` behavior.